# Running an Ant task before Debug in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant

I've got an Ant task that when launched will update the version number in a text file. Is it possible to have this run before an Eclipse Run / Debug configuration besides manually running it each time?

I think in another IDE it's called "compilation trigger" and "execution trigger".

Summary:

1. Click debug icon on Eclipse toolbar
2. An Ant task that I specify runs
3. Debug configuration for current project runs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a "compilation trigger" by adding a new Builder to your project. In your project properties, select Builders and click on new Ant Builder. Then select the build xml and the target that you want to run. This task will then be integrated into all your builds.

Comment: This isn't quite the full answer.  Can you make that Builder call a run or debug launch configuration?